# Ist der Satz grammatisch korrekt? "hat... machen müssen"

Tags: grammaticality, grammar-identification

In "Berlin Alexanderplatz" von Alfred Döblin:

> Es gab Schläge, die Polizei, und zuletzt **hat** der alte Zannowich mit seinen Kindern lange Beine **machen müssen**.

Was für eine Konstruktion ist es? Sollte hier vielleicht Partizip II erscheinen?

Ich bin kein Muttersprachler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Es handelt sich um das Perfekt eines Modalverbs. Es wird im Hochdeutschen mit dem **Ersatzinfinitiv** anstatt des Partizips II gebildet.

> Du musst es machen. Du musstest es machen. Du hast es machen müssen.
>
> Sie soll kommen. Sie sollte kommen. Sie hat kommen sollen.

Das Süddeutsche verwendet jedoch das *Partizip II*.

> Er hat gehen gesollt.

Für Norddeutsche klingt das arg seltsam.