# Why is the finite verb in front of the infinitives in this subordinate clause

Tags: grammaticality, verbal-complex

[image: German exam]

> Nach dem Unfall ist der Autofahrer schwer verletzt ins Krankenhaus gebracht worden, daher waren die Ärzte der Meinung, dass er sofort **hat** operiert werden müssen.

This question is from the German language exam of Turkey.
The paper says answer is B.

Why is the answer B (*hat*)?
Why is the *hat* not at the end of the sentence after *müssen*?
Is the question and/or answer correct?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots. Among other reasons, they are not searchable. I edited the relevant sentence into your post. Feel free to remove references to the answer being B. After all, the issue is that the finite verb occurs in an unexpected position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gleich am Anfang eine Bemerkung, dann haben wir es gleich hinter uns: der Satz ist wirklich kein gutes Schriftdeutsch. Von den zur Verfügung stehenden Möglichkeiten ist "hat" zwar ziemlich die einzig mögliche, aber die Verwendung des Perfekts "hat müssen" in diesem dass-Satz ist nicht hochdeutsch, sondern klar süddeutsch-regional, zum Beispiel könnte der Autor Tiroler, Schwabe oder Bayer sein. Für Deutschlerner ist das sicher eine sehr schwierige Frage. Im Hochdeutschen würde der Satz m.E. lauten:

> ... daher waren die Ärzte der Meinung, dass er sofort operiert werden müsse.

oder

> ... daher waren die Ärzte der Meinung, dass er sofort operiert werden musste.

Wenn man einfach mal annimmt, dass der zu Prüfende hier seine Kenntnisse in  süddeutschem Sprachgebrauch unter Beweis stellen soll, dann kommt man auf folgenden Weg zur richtigen Lösung:

1)
Wenn man den unvollständigen Nebensatz und die Lösungsmöglichkeiten liest, wird schon von Anfang an der Sinn klar: der Patient musste sofort operiert werden. Das einzige, was einzufügen ist, ist das richtige Hilfverb. Das zweite Verb, das direkt an dem Hilfswerb hängt, ist "müssen".

2)
Welche Hilfsverben passen nun überhaupt zu "müssen", wenn man den Satzzusammenhang erstmal außen vor lässt?

"Er wird müssen" würde zunächst schon mal gehen, wenn es Futur sein soll.

<strike>"Er wurde müssen"</strike> kann es nicht sein, "wurde" steht immer mit dem Passiv-Partizip, um einen Passiv zu bilden, nicht mit dem Infinitiv.

"Er hat müssen" ist möglich, das ist das Perfekt für "müssen" als Hilfsverb. Bei bestimmten Hilfsverben wird das Perfekt nicht mit dem Partizip ("gemusst") gebildet, sondern mit dem Infinitiv.

"Er war müssen" und "er ist müssen" ist beides nicht möglich, das Perfekt von "müssen" wird mit "haben" gebildet. "Müssen" ist keines der Verben der Bewegung, deren Perfekt mit "sein" gebildet wird. Auch sonst gibt es keine Form von "müssen", die mit "sein" gebildet wird.

3)
Bleiben also noch "hat" und "wird".

Nun kommt der Satzzusammenhang zum Tragen. Der dass-Satz, über den wir reden, ist ein abhängiger Nebensatz von "Daher waren die Ärzte der Meinung ...". Normalerweise folgt eine indirekte Rede, die im Konjunktiv stehen müsste, also in diesem Fall mit "würde" oder "habe". Die stehen aber beide nicht zur Auswahl -- der Nebensatz steht also im Indikativ und wird beherrscht von einem Satz, der in der Vergangenheitsform steht, und der Zusammenhang zwischen den Zeiten des Hauptsatzen und des Nebensatzen wird von dem Wort "sofort" beschrieben. Es geht also um etwas, das in der Vergangenheit "sofort" passieren musste.

Und damit wird zuletzt die Möglichkeit, dass "wird" gemeint ist, auch sehr unwahrscheinlich, denn wegen des Indikativs statt Konjunktivs müsste die Operation  auch zum Sprechzeitpunkt noch in der Zukunft liegen. Das würde aber dem "sofort" widersprechen.

Ich würde zusammenfassend sagen, die Lösungen "wird" und "hat" sind aus der Sicht des Schriftdeutschen beide fast gleich falsch, aber "hat" entspricht sowohl eher dem Sinn des Satzes als auch dem in Süddeutschland üblichen Sprachgebrauch, deshalb ist es einigermaßen sicher die gewünschte Lösung.

Zuletzt noch zu der Frage, warum das "hat" vor den Infinitiven steht: das ist eine Eigenart des Perfekts von Hilfsverben, bei denen das Perfekt mit Infinitiv gebildet wird, da steht die Form von "haben" oder "sein", die das Hilfsverb ins Perfekt setzt, immer vor den mindestens zwei abhängigen Infinitiven:

> > Präsens: Sie kann ihm nicht helfen 
> > Perfekt: Sie hat ihm nicht helfen können 
> > Perfekt im Nebensatz: Sie ist traurig, weil sie ihm nicht hat helfen können.

Wenn das "können" nicht als Hilfsverb, sondern als Hauptverb benutzt wird, sieht das Perfekt und auch die Wortreihenfolge dagegen viel "normaler" aus:

> > Perfekt: Sie hat in der Prüfung nichts gekonnt 
> > Perfekt im Nebensatz: Sie ist durchgefallen, weil sie in der Prüfung nichts gekonnt hat.

Comment: Glass klar. Danke schön.

Comment: Consider comparing this answer with this previous answer: (https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/50623/ist-der-satz-grammatisch-korrekt-hat-machen-m%C3%BCssen).

Comment: @user46310: Naja, ich finde zumindest nicht, dass sich das widerspricht. Der Gebrauch des Partizips in "Er hat gehen gesollt." scheint mir noch sehr viel weniger verbreitet bzw. noch eine Stufe mundartlicher als der übermäßige Gebrauch des Perfekts, den ich in der Antwort angesprochen habe. Ich habe da aber natürlich auch keine Zahlen.

Comment: @HalvarF Wenn ich die Antwort von @ Janka richtig verstehe, bezweifeln sie weder, dass es Hochdeutsch oder "gutes Schriftdeutsch" ist noch behaupten sie, dass es sueddeutscher Sprachgebrauch sei. Dem wuerde ich mich anschliessen. Ich stimme zu, dass die ersten zwei Alternativen, die hier in der Antwort aufgefuehrt sind, gelaeufiger erscheinen, aber ich denke, dass es subtile Unterschiede zwischen den Varianten gibt, die allerdings vermutlich in gesprochener Sprache kaum wahrgenommen werden.

Comment: @user46310: das ist vielleicht ein Missverständnis: ich sage nicht, dass das Perfekt mit Infinitiv bei Hilfsverben süddeutscher Sprachgebrauch ist, ich sage nur, dass das für die Verwendung des Perfekts im Beispiel-Nebensatz gilt. Ich halte es für eingermaßen ausgeschlossen, dass ein Norddeutscher, Berliner oder Rheinländer den Satz "daher waren die Ärzte der Meinung, dass er sofort hat operiert werden müssen" bildet. Ich wohne jetzt in Baden, und da würde mich das im mündlichen Gebrauch überhaupt nicht wundern.

Comment: Ich bin mir da nicht so sicher, denn es wird ein spezifischer Sachverhalt ausgedrueckt: “Daher waren die Aerzte der Meinung, dass er sofort hat operiert werden muessen.”, d.h. die Aerzte waren nicht nur der Meinung, sondern er wurde tatsaechlich operiert. Waehrend dies nicht deutlich werden wuerde in: “Daher waren die Aerzte der Meinung, dass er sofort operiert werden muesse.” und wenigsten fuer mein Ohr wird das auch nicht klar in “Daher waren die Aerzte der Meinung, dass er sofort operiert werden musste.”

Comment: Gut, da sind wir dann tatsächlich unterschiedlicher Meinung. Ein Dass-Satz unter "die Ärzte waren der Meinung...", und dessen Tempus allein soll gleich mit ausdrücken, dass die Operation tatsächlich stattgefunden hat, und das alles soll dann auch noch Schriftsprache sein. Das passt für mich nicht zusammen. Weitere Diskussion ggf. im Chat.

Comment: Ich will die Diskussion nicht unnötig verlängern, aber: 1) ich denke nicht, dass es hier um eine süddeutsche Bevorzugung des Präteritums gegenüber dem Perfekt geht. Der Lerner soll die ungewöhnliche Position des finiten Verbs und den Ersatzinfinitiv verarbeiten können. 2) Alle Argumente, die das Perfekt hier abwerten, werden hinfällig, wenn man stattdessen den "Konjunktiv der Vergangenheit" setzt, wo die identische Konstellation auftritt: *dass er sofort hätte operiert werden müssen*. 3) Der Satz ist natürlich trotzdem extrem schlecht formuliert.

Comment: zu 1): das sagt ja niemand, sondern umgekehrt, im Süddeutschen wird das Perfekt bevorzugt, und ich glaube auch nicht *wirklich*, dass das hier Absicht war, sondern eher, dass die Person, die die Frage geschrieben hat, eben selbst süddeutsch ist. Zu 2): Der Konjunktiv der Vergangenheit ist für mich kein vergleichbarer Fall, weil es im Konjunktiv schlicht keine andere Möglichkeit gibt, dasselbe auszudrücken, als die Perfektform, und sie deshalb da natürlich völiig in Ordnung ist. Das sagt nichts über den Gebvrauch im Indikativ aus.

Comment: Dein erster Beispielsatz ("...dass er ... müsse") ist von der Zeitfolge her einfach falsch. Zugegeben, da nimmt es das Deutsche nicht so genau, aber hier ist das ein offensichtlicher Fehler. Nimmt man es im Deutschen genauso genau mit der Zeitfolge wie z.B. im Englischen, dann ist das Original die einzig richtige Lösung (zugegebenermaßen eher ungebräuchlich, und zwar überall), unabhängig davon, ob süddeutsch oder nicht. Einen Lernenden verwirrt deine Antwort aber leider mehr, als dass sie hilft - auch wenn du dir sehr viel Mühe gegeben hast.

Comment: @tofro: der erste Beispielsatz ist die korrekte indirekte Rede, die hier  das einzig angemessene ist. wenn man die Meinung der Ärzte nicht als eigene Meinung übernehmen möchte. Da liegst du wirklich komplett falsch. Darüber, ob "dass er sofort hat operiert werden müssen" hier süddeutscher Sprachgebrauch ist, wie ich behaupte, kann man noch diskutieren, aber darüber sicher nicht.

Comment: @tofro: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indirekte_Rede#Tempus